# How to combine multiple SELECT statements into a single query & get a single result output

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have multiple SELECT queries which is ran against different tables.
The output of all the queries have the same number of rows (every query when ran individually will have the same number of rows). Is there a way I can combine the output of all these queries into a single result? (Keep out from first query and add the output of next query as a column to the output of the next query). I dont want to save these tables into database as I am just doing some validation testing.

Example:

```
SELECT AAA,BBB,CCC FROM Table1 

SELECT Table2.DDD, Table1.AAA
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table1.AAA = Table2.AAA
```

I tried writing combining the query as

```
SELECT Table1.AAA,Table1.BBB,Table1.CCC,T1.DDD
FROM Table1, 
(SELECT Table2.DDD, Table1.AAA
FROM Table2 
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table1.AAA = Table2.AAA)T1
```

I tried doing the above combined query, but instead of getting 11 rows as output (both queries above had result of 11 rows), I am getting 35 rows as output.

Hope the question made sense!

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to specify a criteria to match each row the first query with which row of the second query.

Comment: UNION ALL, or JOIN.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify a criteria to match each row the first query with which row of the second query.

If, for example, the column `AAA` is unique in both queries and you want to match rows with the same values you could do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from (
  SELECT AAA,BBB,CCC FROM Table1
) a
full join join (
  SELECT Table2.DDD, Table1.AAA
  FROM Table2
  INNER JOIN Table1
  ON Table1.AAA = Table2.AAA
) b on b.aaa = a.aaa
```

If there aren't any clear matching rules, you can produce an **artificial row number** on each result set and use it to match rows. For example:

```
select
  a.aaa, a.bbb, a.ccc,
  b.ddd, b.aaa
from (
  SELECT AAA, BBB, CCC,
    row_number() over(order by aaa) as rn
   FROM Table1
) a
full join join (
  SELECT Table2.DDD, Table1.AAA,
    row_number() over(order by table1.aaa, table2.ddd) as rn
  FROM Table2
  INNER JOIN Table1
  ON Table1.AAA = Table2.AAA
) b on b.rn = a.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several results and want to have all of them as additional columns you can simply use ",":

```
create table temp1 as select '1' as c1 from DUAL;
create table temp2 as select '2' as c2 from DUAL;
create table temp3 as select '3' as c3 from DUAL;

select a.c1, b.c2, c.c3 from temp1 a, (select c2 from temp2) b,  (select c3 from temp3) c;
```

An alternative could also be that you want to have all the results as additional rows then you would use `UNION ALL` between the individual results.